# Load local image with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, image, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Jetpack Compose in an Android app. I need to load images and I use:

```
Image(
    modifier = centerHorizontal
        .size(AppSize.profileImage)
        .border(
            width = AppSize.line,
            color = Color.White,
            shape = AppCircleShape()
        ),
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data = profile.image,
        builder = {
            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.profile_image)
)
```

It works fine.
Now I need to load local images that I have downloaded using the DownloadManager.
The download manager is set up to download the images in the `Download` folder. They end being in the folder `/storage/emulated/0/Download`. I verified that the images are there.

The problem is that I don't know how to show them.
Do I have to run a local web server to expose them?

I tried to use `"file://${user.profile}"`, that works on Chrome, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a file path, try to transfer the file,please try

```
val path = ...
Image(rememberImagePainter(File(path)),
      contentDescription = ""
)
```

Comment: I set it as accepted because it seems to be the right answer although so far it is still not working. I checked that File(path).exists() returns true but the image is still not shown. It is if I use the URL that points to the file on the Internet instead of the File

Comment: And the file that exists is correct because I can show it on Chrome pointint to the same File

Comment: It is a problem with the particular folder. If I store the image in the app folder then everything works. If I have the images in the download folder, where the DownloadManager stores it, it doesn't work even if the files are there and the app managed to write in that folder

Comment: I needed to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>